# How to use the Python serialization library (serial) alongside the serial port access library (pyserial)

Tags: python, python-import, pyserial, python-module, name-collision

I want to use the *serial* and the *pyserial* library in the same Python script. The problem is that both libraries are imported using the same statement:

```py
import serial
```

There are many questions regarding this name collision on SO which are usually about someone wanting to use PySerial but importing the serialization library instead as the import statement prioritizes the latter. My issue is that I want to use both libraries.

I am using Python 3.10.0 on Windows 11.